# How to remove plotted lines on TradingView Pine Script and just get values?

Tags: pine-script

Basically I've written a super simple indicator to quickly calculate my lot size, TP and SL. It works exactly how I want to except it obviously plots the lines on the chart which completely screws up my scale, meaning I'd have to keep scrolling back forever whenever I rescaled.

```
indicator(title="Lot Size Calculator", shorttitle="LotSize",overlay=true,precision=2)

amount = input.int(title="Amount",defval=1000,minval=1)
stopsize = input.int(title="Stop Loss Size", defval=100, minval=10)

//Lot Size
plot(amount / stopsize, color=color.yellow) 

//Stop Loss Size

plot(stopsize, color=color.red)

//Take Profit Size

plot(stopsize * 1.30, color=color.green)*
```

Basically I'd like to keep the values in the top left corner but completely remove the plotted lines, is there a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `plotchar()` without any `char`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

plotchar(close/10, "Ten", "")
plotchar(close/100, "Hundred", "")
plotchar(close/1000, "Thousand", "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, transparency is set to 100, so is visible only in Data Window

```
plot(stopsize, color=color.new(color.red, 100) )
```